Whare is the place to ask about translating epilepsy terminology and classification?
In specific I want to inquire about the terminology on severity( intensity) and not the location.
I am pretty sure that Εστιακές would be translated as Partial or Focal. And Γενικευμένη would be translated as Generalized. Partial Epilepsy affects only one hemisphere whie Generalized affects both hemispheres.
Απλές would be translated as Simple.
My problem is translating Σύνθετη and Σύμπλοκη.
In one you get "just" Abstractions while for the other you get more severe consiousness symtoms like Forgetting what you did during the seizure or even Fainting.
The supposed question(the one I am inquiring, looking where to ask, about now) that I would ask would be:

Which one gets translated as Complex and how does the other one get
  translated?

In a nutshell repeating the title and the meta-question the question I am looking for answers here in the meta site.

Whare is the place to ask about translating epilepsy terminology and classification?


Since you already have the symptoms, it seems to me that the source language terms are unnecessary - why not just ask the classification question based on the symptoms and background detail that you provided?  Note that the psych.SE community is very small.  I'm not sure what language this is (Greek?), but the sub-group of users capable of answering translation questions is possibly non-existent.

Sidenote: "Partial Epilepsy affects only one hemisphere whie Generalized affects both hemispheres." That is not how I remember it. The definition is not linked to hemispheres: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seizure_types

And, I agree with Arnon. You can ask about the specific symptoms, and even the Greek translations as background/context information. You should be able to piece together your answer.

@ArnonWeinberg Is there actually a distinct term for the severity in complex partial seizures? Greek has the distinction but the wikipedia page notes only Complex( and all the dictionaries will give me that both Σύνθετη and Σύμπλοκη are translated to Complex at least linguistically). Maybe just the Greek physicians like to come up with more distinction than those found in mainstream standart science.

I don't know, but that seems like a fine question to ask on the forum.

@ArnonWeinberg Did you have a specific forum in mind when using the definite article? Does Psychology.Stackexchange have a forum? I do not have any forum in mind where I can ask such a question. Did you mean the main site by any chance?

Isn't Greek a 'dead language'?  As such, would there exist a term at all for focal epilepsy in Greek at all?

@AliceD It certainly is not. I speak Greek in fact. As most Greek doctors do when treating patients in Greece.

Thanks for that. There is also no Greek.SE unfortunately. Only a Latin SE site. Are there Greek journals on epilepsy? Good luck!

@AliceD There are Greek journals. What in fact happens is that all the terms are impoper the correct characterization therefore is no Complex Partial Epilepsy but rather Epilepsy with X,Y, and Z symptoms. One describes it periphrastically and not with a single term.

Terminology around epilepsy is really complex (I suffer from it myself, and have done some research on it too, in a distant past mind you :-). Have you considered the possibility that seizures can be complex partial, but not the underlying etiology (epilepsy)? Isn't that the reason that the authors you describe describe the etiology, seemingly, in a less direct way?

@AliceD It is not the etiology that they describe it is the symptomatology and pathophysiology. Instead of describing it with one word. They give a paragraph lenght description.
